# min value of a column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following code :

```
from __future__ import division
import pyodbc
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

count = 1
dsn = "DRIVER={SQL Server};server=XXXX;database=ABCD"
conn = pyodbc.connect(dsn)
cursor = conn.cursor()
#policy = cursor.execute("select distinct client_num, py_type, py_num, max(ex_date_n) as ex_date_n, max(ef_date_n) as ef_date_n from dbo.policy group by client_num, py_type, py_num")
policy = cursor.execute("select distinct client_num, py_type, py_num, max(ex_date_n) as ex_date_n,max(ef_date_n) as ef_date_n from dbo.policy where client_num = 62961 and py_type = 'A' and py_num = '01' group by client_num, py_type, py_num")
results1 = cursor.fetchall()

for row in results1:
    pol_client_num = row.client_num.strip()
    pol_py_type = row.py_type.strip()
    pol_py_num = row.py_num.strip()
    pol_number = pol_client_num+pol_py_type+pol_py_num
    pol_exp_date = row.ex_date_n
    pol_eff_date = row.ef_date_n
    #related = cursor.execute("select distinct a.client_num,a.py_type,a.py_num,a.rclient_num,a.py_rtype,a.rpy_num from policy_replace a where a.client_num = "+pol_client_num+" and a.py_type = '"+pol_py_type+"' and a.py_num = '"+pol_py_num+"'")
    related = cursor.execute("select distinct a.client_num,a.py_type,a.py_num,a.rclient_num,a.py_rtype,a.rpy_num from policy_replace a where a.client_num = 62961 and a.py_type = 'A' and a.py_num = 01")
    results2 = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in results2:
        rel_client_num = row.rclient_num.strip()
        rel_py_type = row.py_rtype.strip()
        rel_py_num = row.rpy_num.strip()
        rel_pol_number = rel_client_num+rel_py_type+rel_py_num
        related_dates = cursor.execute("select max(b.ex_date_n) as ex_date_n, b.ef_date_n from policy b where b.ex_date_n >= 20200225 and b.client_num = "+rel_client_num+" and b.py_type = '"+rel_py_type+"' and b.py_num = '"+rel_py_num+"' group by b.ef_date_n")
        #related_dates = cursor.execute("select max(b.ex_date_n) as ex_date_n, b.ef_date_n from policy b where b.client_num = 37916 and b.py_type = 'F' and b.py_num = 05 group by b.ef_date_n")
        results3 = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in results3:            
            rel_exp_date = row.ex_date_n
            rel_eff_date = row.ef_date_n
            final_result1 = (pol_number,pol_exp_date,pol_eff_date,rel_pol_number,rel_exp_date,rel_eff_date)
        df = pd.DataFrame(final_result1)
        df = df.transpose()
        df.columns = ['pol_number','pol_exp_date','pol_eff_date','rel_pol_number','rel_exp_date','rel_eff_date']
        df_grouped = df.groupby('pol_number')['rel_exp_date'].min()
        print(df_grouped)
print('done')
```

On execution, the following is the data output:
For results1,

```
'62961 ', 'A', '01', 20210429, 20200429
```

For results2,

```
('62961 ', 'A', '01', '62961', 'A', '02'), 
('62961 ', 'A', '01', '62961', 'A', '03'), 
('62961 ', 'A', '01', '63832', 'A', '01')
```

For results3,

```
[(20201107, 20191107)]
[(20210407, 20200407)] 
[(20200719, 20190719)]
```

The expected output is as follows:

```
'69621','A','01',20210429,20200429,'69621','A','02',20201107,20191107,'62961','A','03',20210407,20200407,'63832','A','01',20200719,20190719,'63832','A','01',20200719,20190719
```

The format of the output required is :
for every row in results1 --- every related row in results2 --- every related date in results3  --- minimum of the exp_date across all rows and the corresponding pol_num/rel_pol_num
This is the reason I am trying to use the df.min() function to get the min across all the exp_date's. But, it doesn't seem to do the job since I am possibly missing something. I also tried axis = 0 as mentioned in the comments but it didn't work. Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: Please, spend some time reading [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: if I understand your question correctly, you are looking for min(rel_exp_date) to populate min column for values in pol_number group: try adding axis=0 to your groupby.  If I don't understand correctly, please add more detail to your posting to help others understand to help you.

Comment: Your understanding was right. I have added additional details to the original question